# Python on OS X: Getting local date time patterns

Tags: python, macos

Has anyone managed to use locale on OS X to derive a default local date and time format ? (I need to parse simple dates and times in a variety of locales).

For the moment, I am resorting to osascript …

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = "osascript -e " + """'
    tell (current date)
        set {its year, its month, its day} to {2001, 2, 3}
        set {its hours, its minutes, its seconds} to {4, 5, 6}
        return its short date string & tab & its time string
    end tell'"""

str_date, err_num = Popen(cmd, shell=True, \
    stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()

str_date, _, str_time = str_date.rpartition('   ')
str_date_pattern = str_date.replace('2001', '%Y').replace('02', '%m').replace('03','%d')
str_time_pattern = str_time.replace('04', '%H').replace('05', '%M').replace('06', '%S').rstrip()
```

which returns something like:

```
'%d/%m/%Y', '%H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the [`python-dateutil` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) instead?

It's [`parse` function](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) can handle most formats *without* having to configure the format:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('03/02/2001 04:05:06')
datetime.datetime(2001, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6)
```

Alternatively, you could try and translate the [ICU format strings](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) available via the `defaults read` command:

```
$ defaults read .GlobalPreferences AppleICUDateFormatStrings
{
    1 = "yyyy/M/d";
}
$ defaults read .GlobalPreferences AppleICUTimeFormatStrings
{
    1 = "kk:mm ";
    2 = "kk:mm:ss ";
    3 = "kk:mm:ss  z";
    4 = "kk:mm:ss  v";
}
```

These are the locale settings configured via the `Language & Text` configuration panel.

Comment: Thanks ! *dateutil* looks optimal, tho for ease of distribution I'm trying to keep to default libraries. *defaults read* is a good idea (and I guess variants of *date %x* etc through the shell would be simpler than osascript too).

Comment: Curiously enough, piping output from *defaults read .GlobalPreferences* through *grep* reveals no date or time FormatStrings on this (10.7.5) system, though the locale string is in there.

Comment: @houthakker: Make sure you do a case insensitive grep (`-i`) :-P I use 10.7.5 myself, *and* used grep to find those.

Comment: Yes, I did take that precaution :-) but on this system the only strings containing any case variant of *date* or *time* in *.GlobalPreferences* are: *NSNavModDateFileProperty*, *modDate* plus *Centimeters* and *DefaultTimeZoneNames* (as visual inspection of the whole plist confirms) Something to do with use of multiple languages ?

Comment: typo: in bash: *date "+%x +%X"*

Comment: Or more fully:
    *date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" "2001/2/3 04:05:06" +"%x %X"*

Comment: Possibly to do with default settings and no recorded deviation from that default?

Comment: That does sound right - I think those keys get set when when customise.

Comment: @houthakker: It is indeed only set if the user explicitly changed the default. The defaults are those provided for the POSIX locale, I believe, so you can use the `locale` module `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)` and `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.T_FMT)` values if `AppleICUDateFormatStrings` and `AppleICUTimeFormatStrings` are not set.

Comment: Thanks !  `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)` and `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.T_FMT)` work well.